# Why is Multiple Type-Casting Required?

Tags: java, casting

Consider the following hierarchy:

```
TopClass
      |__ MiddleClass
                  |__ BottomClass
```

Then the following code is of-course not required:

```
public BottomClass getBottom() {
    return (BottomClass) (MiddleClass) getObject();
}
```

Where `getObject()` returns an instance of type `BottomClass` but has a return type of `TopClass`.

You could effectivily short-circuit it, and cast directly to `BottomClass`.

---

But this code raised my brows:

In the JavaFX source package,
class: `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ProgressIndicatorSkin`

```
@Override
public StyleableProperty<Paint> getStyleableProperty(ProgressIndicator n) {
    final ProgressIndicatorSkin skin = (ProgressIndicatorSkin) n.getSkin();
        return (StyleableProperty<Paint>)(WritableValue<Paint>)skin.progressColor;
}
```

Where the interface hierarchy is:

```
WritableValue<T>
              |__ StyleableProperty<T>
```

And `progressColor` is of type `StyleableObjectProperty<Paint>`, that implements `StyleableProperty<Paint>`, but is stored in an `ObjectProperty<Paint>` variable, like this:

```
private ObjectProperty<Paint> progressColor = new StyleableObjectProperty<Paint>(null)
```

Any clue what's going on here?

Comment: Did you try removing the intermediate cast? Did it give an error? What did the error say?

Comment: It appears to just be unnecessary code, but I'm not familiar enough with JavaFX to know if there's some unseen reason.

Comment: It's not my code, it's part of the JDK. And probably doesn't require knowledge in JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intermediary cast seems unnecessary. Direct cast should work.

However, the direct cast would be a "cross" cast - casting between two types  that has no apparent subtype relationship.

The programmer probably doesn't want that; instead, it's more comfortable for the programmer to upcast to a nearest common supertype, then do a downcast, which feels "safer".

---

Discussion of casts:

It's always safe to do an "up" cast

```
    (Animal)cat
```

It is allowed to do a "down" cast; the compiler assumes the programmer knows better about the actual runtime type

```
    (Cat)animal
```

It is the "cross" cast that is a problem. Sometimes it is obvious that the cross-cast is impossible

```
    (Cat)dog   // Cat and Dog are two classes, and no subclass relation

    (List<Cat>) listDog   //  List<Dog> => List<Cat>

    (Runnable)fish    // Fish is a final class that does not implement Runnable
```

However, if it is not *provably* incorrect, the compiler would allow it, trusting the programmer

```
     (Runnable)animal   // Animal class does not implement Runnable; but a subclass may
```

We can always cast between any two types by going through a common supertype

```
     (List<Cat>)(List<?>) listDog
```

Of course, Object is the common supertype of all types, so we can use it to force any casts

```
     (Cat)(Object)dog
```

Comment: Wow! never knew _that_. But in my case, `StyleableObjectProperty` does implement `StyleableProperty` directly?

Comment: @MouseEvent - the static type of `skin.progressColor` is `ObjectProperty`

Comment: Super, I now noticed that `ObjectProperty` implements `WritableValue`.